# Rails Multi-step form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm writing a quiz app with rails 5. I have got a multi-step form for question building.

Models:

```
class Mcq < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :option_count
  has_many :options, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :quiz

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options
  validates :question_text, presence: true
end

class Option < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :mcq, optional: true
  validates :option_text, presence: true
end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "mcqs", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "question_text"
  t.boolean  "required"
  t.boolean  "multiselect"
  t.integer  "quiz_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
end


create_table "options", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "option_text"
  t.integer  "mcq_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
```

The first page is for question setup and has the following fields:

1. Option Count
2. Required (Yes / No)
3. No of options that can be selected (Single / Multiple)

The second page is for options and has the following fields:

1. Question Text
2. Nested Form for Options

Controller:

```
class McqsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    session[:current_step] ||= 'setup'
    session[:mcq_params] ||= {}

    @current_step = session[:current_step]
    @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:quiz_id])
    @mcq = Mcq.new(session[:mcq_params])

    if session[:current_step] == 'options'
      @option_count = session[:mcq_params]['option_count']
      @option_count.times { @mcq.options.build }
    end
  end

  def create
    if params[:previous_button]
      session[:current_step] = 'setup'
      redirect_to new_quiz_mcq_path
    elsif session[:current_step] == 'setup'
      save_session(params[:mcq])
      redirect_to new_quiz_mcq_path
    elsif session[:current_step] == 'options'
      @mcq = Mcq.new(whitelisted_mcq_params)
      @mcq.quiz_id = params[:quiz_id]
      @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:quiz_id])
      if @mcq.save
        session[:current_step] = session[:mcq_params] = nil
        redirect_to quiz_new_question_path(@mcq.quiz_id)
      else
        @current_step = session[:current_step]
        render :new
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def whitelisted_mcq_params
    params.require(:mcq)
        .permit(:question_text, :multiselect, :required,    options_attributes: [:option_text])
  end

  def save_session(mcq_params)
     session[:mcq_params][:option_count] = mcq_params[:option_count].to_i
     session[:mcq_params][:required] = mcq_params[:required]
     session[:mcq_params][:multiselect] = mcq_params[:multiselect]
     session[:current_step] = 'options'
  end
end
```

The above solution works, but the code is messy and difficult to understand. I came across this [railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms) which does something similar in a cleaner way. I've updated my code as follows:

```
class Mcq < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :options, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :quiz

  attr_writer :current_step
  attr_accessor :option_count

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :options
  validates :question_text, presence: true

  def current_step
    @current_step || steps.first
  end

  def steps
    %w[setup options]
  end

  def next_step
    self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)+1]
  end

  def previous_step
    self.current_step = steps[steps.index(current_step)-1]
  end

  def last_step?
    current_step == steps.last
  end
end

class McqsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    session[:mcq_params] ||= {}
    @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:quiz_id])
    @mcq = Mcq.new(session[:mcq_params])
    @mcq.current_step = session[:mcq_step]
  end

  def create
    @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:quiz_id])
    session[:mcq_params].deep_merge!(params[:mcq]) if params[:mcq]
    @mcq = Mcq.new(session[:mcq_params])

    @option_count = session[:mcq_params]['option_count']
    @option_count.times { @mcq.options.build }

    @mcq.quiz_id = params[:quiz_id]
    @mcq.current_step = session[:mcq_step]

    if params[:previous_button]
      @mcq.previous_step
    elsif @mcq.last_step?
      @mcq.save if @mcq.valid?
    else
      @mcq.next_step
    end
    session[:mcq_step] = @mcq.current_step

    if @mcq.new_record?
      render "new"
    else
      session[:mcq_step] = session[:mcq_params] = nil
      redirect_to edit_quiz_path(@mcq.quiz_id)
    end
  end
end
```

But each time the second page is shown, the no of fields for options doubles or in case of invalid entry only the field for question_text is shown. How do I show the options correctly? Should I just go with my first solution? I'm new to rails and don't know much about the best practices.

Edited :

new.html.erb

```
<div class="sub-heading">Add a Multiple Choice Question:</div>

<%= render "mcq_#{@mcq.current_step}", quiz: @quiz, mcq: @mcq %>
```

_mcq_setup.html.erb

```
<div class="form-container">
  <%= form_for [quiz, mcq] do |f| %>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="response-count">How many options should the question have?</div>
      <%= f.select(:option_count, (2..5)) %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="response-count">How many options can be selected?</div>

      <div class="option">
        <%= f.radio_button :multiselect, 'false', checked: true %>
        <%= f.label :multiselect, 'Just One', value: 'false' %>
      </div>

      <div class="option">
        <%= f.radio_button :multiselect, 'true' %>
        <%= f.label :multiselect, 'Multiple', value: 'true' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="response-count">Is the question required?</div>

      <div class="option">
        <%= f.radio_button :required, 'true', checked: true %>
        <%= f.label :required, 'Yes', value: 'true' %>
      </div>

      <div class="option">
        <%= f.radio_button :required, 'false' %>
        <%= f.label :required, 'No', value: 'false' %>
      </div>

    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Continue to the Next Step" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

_mcq_options.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [quiz, mcq] do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :question_text, 'What is your question?' %>
  <%= f.text_field :question_text %>

  <%= f.fields_for :options do |option_fields| %>
    <%= option_fields.label :option_text, "Option #{option_fields.options[:child_index] + 1}:" %>
    <%= option_fields.text_field :option_text %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :multiselect %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :required %>

  <%= f.submit "Add Question" %>
  <%= f.submit "Back to previous step", name: 'previous_button' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Might be helpful to see the views.

Comment: I've edited the question to add views.

Comment: You could always build a front end form using JavaScript or hold the input in a session hash between requests before deleting it after the request has been submitted following the final page of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You may look in direction of [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine). By using that you can use your steps as states of state machine and use its ability to define validations that only active for given states (look [here](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine#activerecord) in `state :first_gear, :second_gear do`) so fields that required on second step will be not required on first. Also, it'll allow you to avoid complex checks for the step you currently on (because the state will be persisted in a model) and will be pretty easy to extend with more steps in a future.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to do this without using any additional plugins or gems.

Comment: As long as you have only a few steps, you can enforce the same trick with validations using [conditional validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless).